# How to replace text in a file with str_replace?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, str-replace

Something like this:

```
$vars = array("key" => "value", "key2" => "value2" //..etc);

function ($template, $vars) {
  $file = file_get_contents($template);
  foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
    str_replace($template //this is where I get confused);

  }
}
```

The idea is to get contents of a template file(includes only html) then the foreach will run and replace text that is the "key" inside the vars array, with text that is the "value" field inside the vars array. So lets say I have somewhere in my template file text like this "{content}". The function should find that string(including the braces I know I didn't specify them in my example) and replace it with the corresponding value inside the array.

I feel like I don't understand the str_replace() function enough. PHP.net doesn't help much either, as I understand it it goes like this:

```
str_replace($replacethese, $withthese, $inthisfile);
```

Simple enough, but how can I do that when my array is two dimensional? My "$replacethese" argument would have to be the "key" values of the $vars array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `array_keys()` and `array_values()` to get the keys and values of `$vars`. Try this:

```
$replace = array_keys($vars);
$with = array_values($vars);
$file = str_replace($replace, $with, $file);
```

**EDIT:**

@E L says that `strtr()` is better :) . So you can try:

```
$file = strtr($file, $vars);
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need foreach loop just single str_replace call like this will do the job:

```
str_replace(array_keys($vars), array_values($vars), $fileData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function ($template, $vars) {
  $data = file_get_contents($template);
  $data = str_replace(array_keys($vars), array_values($vars), $data);
  file_put_contents($template, $data);
}
```